# color value in a loop maya

Tags: 3d, maya, mel

Can someone please help me with this simple script.

I just want to apply the material color that is in an array.

Here is what I have for now.
How can I link so that my material two("colors2") looks for values `$dp_matColor[3]`,`$dp_matColor[4]`,`$dp_matColor[5]`?

It looks like I need an if statement but not sure what condition I need to add.

BTW I will have more than two materials

My final goal is to create button based on `$list_of_names[]`and get the background color from `$dp_matColor[]`.
When I click, it will create my material based on below for loop by using same arrays.

Currently, I can achieve this by having a procedure for every color, but there is a lot of repeated script.

```
string $list_of_names[] = {"color1", "color2"};
float $dp_matColor[] = { 1.0, 0.5, 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 1.0};

for ($eachName in $list_of_names){
    shadingNode -asShader VRayMtl -n $eachName;
    setAttr ($eachName + ".color") -type double3 $dp_matColor[] $dp_matColor[] $dp_matColor[];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use python, you could construct your data to more easily loop through it like this:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

data = [('color1', (1.0, 0.5, 0.5)), ('color2', (0.5, 0.5, 1.0))]

for name, values in data:
    shader = mc.shadingNode(asShader='VRayMtl', n=name)
    mc.setAttr('%s.color' %shader, values, type='double3')
```

I haven't tested that to ensure it works... you may need to put the values in separately ie: `values[0], values[1], values[3]`.  You could also use a dictionary to store the data, or create 2 lists that are in sync with each other... and on and on and on (so many options...)

But to try and do it with mel, this might work (it's been a while since I've used mel... so forgive me if it doesn't work... but the concept is there...):

```
string $list_of_names[] = {"color1", "color2"};
float $dp_matColor[] = { 1.0, 0.5, 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 1.0};

for (i=0;i<size($list_of_names);i++){
    shadingNode -asShader VRayMtl -n $list_of_names[i];
    int $index = i * 3;
    setAttr ($list_of_names[i] + ".color") -type double3 $dp_matColor[$index] $dp_matColor[($index+1)] $dp_matColor[($index+2)];   
}
```

Comment: Thank you such, I was able to achieve the result with your help.I made couple changes.Now, I am not sure how to make the procedure run for each button.I made a different post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530691/link-procedure-to-each-button-command-maya