# Link procedure to each button command maya

Tags: 3d, maya, mel

I made this script that creates two material with different color values.How can I attach this procedure so that when I click color 1 button it creates material color 1 and color 2 when I click second button.If there is a much better way to achieve this is python.Please let me know

```
global string $list_of_names[];
global float $matColor[];
$list_of_names = {"color1","color2"};
$matColor = { 1.0,0.355,0.5,0.545,0.5,1.0};


global proc create() {
global string $list_of_names[];
global float $matColor[];

   for ($i=0; $i<`size $list_of_names`; ++$i){
        shadingNode -asShader VRayMtl -n $list_of_names;
        setAttr ($list_of_names[$i] + ".color") -type double3 $matColor[($i*3)] $matColor[($i*3)+1] $matColor[($i*3)+2];                   
    } 

}


window -width 150;
columnLayout -adjustableColumn true;

for ($i=0; $i<`size $list_of_names`; ++$i){
    button -label $list_of_names[$i] -command "create()";
}

showWindow;
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. You want some Python code that does the exact same thing you did in MEL?
There would be a lot of __different__ (and not _better_) ways of doing this thing in Python (and in MEL as well, to be honest), so can you explain better what do you mean, please?

Comment: I am still a newbie in scripting and I just started learning basic mel coding.I made a procedure that creates two materials and assigns two different colors to them.Now I am stuck at assigning that procedure to buttons based its name.So that when I click color1 it should only create color1 material.I am sure there are different ways to achieve this in mel and especially in python as well.I am ok if it's easy to solve the issue in python as I am interested to see how it looks as my next step is to start learning python.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on your question, this should be what you are looking for:

```
import functools

import maya.cmds

buttons = {
    'color1': (1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    'color2': (0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
}

def button_callback(shader_color):
    print shader_color
    maya.cmds.shadingNode(...)
    maya.cmds.setAttr(...)


w = maya.cmds.window(width=150)
maya.cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True)

for btn in buttons:
    maya.cmds.button(
        label=btn,
        command=functools.partial(button_callback, buttons[btn])
    )

maya.cmds.showWindow()
```

Basically this code does the same thing you are doing in `MEL`, but using python "structure" (because python is an indipendent language from Maya, has some libraries like functools, that helps you doing more complex things that the one that MEL lets you do).

To understand more about it, just look into google for python 2.7.10+ documentation (that is the one used from the last version of Maya).

Also Maya has some documentation about the python function you can use, instead of the MEL ones.